# How to loop over ExampleSets in Rapidminer?

Tags: text-mining, rapidminer

I am trying to extract the data from a pdf without the data in the tables.

- I used "Read PDF Table" which extracts each table from pdf as one ExampleSet. So the output is an ioo object collection of ExampleSets.
- I tried different "Loop" operators to extract text from this ioo object collection (from the above step), but the operators seems to extract only the FIRST ExampleSet in the ioo object collection.

Can someone suggest how to loop over ALL the ExampleSets in the ioo object collection?

Note: Since all the ExampleSets are of different types, I couldn't append or join them.

Answer (score 3):

Specific to your question:
Use the Operator "Append (Superset)" from the "Operator Toolbox Extension". 
This allows you to append ExampleSets even if there are new Attributes or the Attributes have a different value type.

In general regarding looping over a collection:
The Operator of your choice would be "Loop Collection".
The Operators inside this nested Operator are applied on every ExampleSet in the collection and the output is again a collection of ExampleSets.

Happy Mining,
Edin

P.S.:
Have you already checked the RapidMiner Community website (https://community.rapidminer.com)? Maybe you can find possible future questions already answered there?